# I need to have two variables in one sentence, but when I have two it wrote error message: is not a valid XPath expression

Tags: javascript, python, xpath

**When  I have 1 variable it works, but I need 2 and then it wrote error.**

```
product = "Air Force 1 Low"
color = "White"

findJS = (
"""
const $xOne = xp =>document.evaluate(xp, document, null,XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, 
null).singleNodeValue;
($xOne("//*[contains(text(), """+product+""")]/../following-sibling::p/a[contains(text(), 
"""+color+""")]")).click();
"""
)
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: @Barmar Whole error message: Message: invalid element state: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string '//*[contains(text(), Air Force 1 Low)]/../following-sibling::p/a[contains(text(), White)]' is not a valid XPath expression.

Comment: Do you really have a newline before `"""+color+"""`? That creates a newline in the JS string literal, which isn't allowed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second argument to `contains()` should be quoted.

It's easier to write something like this using an f-string rather than concatenation.

```
findJS = f"""
const $xOne = xp =>document.evaluate(xp, document, null,XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue;
$xOne("//*[contains(text(), '{product}')]/../following-sibling::p/a[contains(text(), '{color}')]").click();
"""
```